# Problem adding namespace to XML root VB.net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have some problems adding the namespeace to the root element in my XML.
This is what i need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<T:Test xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema 
test.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:T="http://test.bfa">
```

This is what i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Test xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema Test.xsd" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

My code:

```
Dim xmldecl As XmlDeclaration
xmldecl = xmlDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "")

Dim root As XmlElement = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
xmlDoc.InsertBefore(xmldecl, root)
Dim schemaLocation As XmlAttribute = xmlDoc.CreateAttribute("xsi","schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")
schemaLocation.Value = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema test.xsd"

Dim xmlTestNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement(TEST_NODO)
xmlTestNode.Attributes.Append(schemaLocation)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    Dim rxe As XElement

    rxe = <T:Test xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchematest.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:T="http://test.bfa"></T:Test>

    rxe.Save("your path here")
```

When you save it, it will have the right declaration,

EDIT:

```
    Dim rxe As XElement

    rxe = <T:Test xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchematest.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xmlns:T="http://test.bfa"></T:Test>

    Dim oldXE As XElement
    oldXE = XElement.Load("path to old here")

    rxe.Add(oldXE.Elements)

    rxe.Save("your path here")
```

Comment: @RicardoFernandez - have no idea what your comment means.

Comment: when i do rxe.save(path), my document its completely overwritten with the namespace. I will try to convert the XElement into XMLNode to add it as a child of the root.